# Package all content from a folder using NuGet

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

We would like to use Octopus Deploy for our Deployments. I am trying to package our assemblies using Nuget for the same. We maintain lots of solutions (contains lots of independent projects) and We have our custom windows host which doesn't have any direct reference to the application assemblies. Currently We Zip all the files and extract them to install the windows services. I am exploring a way to package all the content in zip file to NuGet Package. is that possible. What is the best and easiest way to package considering our current implementation. I tried creating .NuSpec file and NuPkg manually using package explorer. But it's not visible and only visible in package explorer.

Comment: http://docs.nuget.org/create/Creating-and-Publishing-a-Package

Comment: Thanks. I manually constructed the nuspec file the way i wanted. It works.

Comment: @RajaRanganathan I have similar requirement I have a .zip file for that I have to create a nuget package. Can you please let me know how you create for your requirement..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can bundle all artifacts by defining metadata inside a nuspec files , nuget package created using that nuspec file will contain all artifacts defined in nuspec file, you can do the whole process from your command line as well , when creation of package is done from command line you can see your package in the same path where nuspec file resides and most important thing nuget package is also a type of zip file , so you can simply rename your example.nupkg to example.zip and verify the bundled contents.

Comment: @Raja Ranganathan if you found my answer helpful please up vote my answer , if it solved your  problem please accept my answer , it will be helpful for others to identify a solution,  thanks ..!!